# How to add actionlisteners to SVG elements so as to bind them to POJOs in Java?

Tags: java, svg

I have a requirement wherein I need to render a certain SVG component on click of some other SVG component with data populated in the rendered component coming from a Java class.In other words the data displayed on the rendered SVG component has to come from a list or any other collections embedded in the Java POJO.
As I understand, we need to have an action listener bound to the SVG component which in turn hits a function in the Java class.
Please help with any pointers on this.

Comment: How are you rendering the SVG? Batik?

Comment: @Robert Longson..I'm using simple HTML embedded SVG element to create the elements. I'm not using Batik because I want to develop a web based application and not a window based one.

Comment: How are you calling Java then?  Do you have a Java applet on your page?  You need to add more detail to your question.

Comment: Well I'm using JSF EL expressions to bind the form components and action buttons to their identifiers and functions respectively in the Java class. I want to achieve the same with SVG elements. Hope it's clear?